# Performance ramifications of using fontsize in each xaml element versus styles in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an XF project very late in the development cycle, and "suddenly" fontsize has become an issue.   It appears that the "default" font size for an iPhone 13 is signficantly bigger than previous generations, especially iPhone 8.  My app was "at risk" of the user pushing the text size up in settings, but this made this much more of a problem.  I am currently focusing only on iOS, and, sad to say, I am holding at XF 4.8 for reasons I won't discuss here.

Most of my code specifies fontsizes for each entity, mostly with a specific size listed in the .xaml file, and many if not most of these are actually linked to system variables so that these can be "tuned" for whether it is iPhone or iPad.

My question is this -- if I go through and carefully add "fontsize=" to the .xaml files, will this cause a big performance hit?

The "right way" to do this, of course, is with styles.  But, I have some styles in App.xaml, but I'm hesitating for two reasons:

1. It would be a lot of work to change this over.  I have more than 20 pages.
2. I'm unsure whether the performance is likely to be better or worse, and if worse, how bad?

As I say, I'm pretty late in the game here -- I don't think I would do a major rework unless it was necessary.   So I'm leaning toward adding the "fontsize=" to .xaml files for now.  Good idea?

Example -- these two labels are on the same page.  One has no fontsize specification and so the letters will be normal, big, or small depending on
Settings->Display & Brightness->Text Size.   The other has a fontsize specified, so changing text size does not affect the size of the letters.  While I'm thinking a really good way would be to use styles, I'm thinking of adding the "fontsize" to any text field that doesn't have it.

```
<Label
    x:Name="LblComboHelp"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    TextColor="White"
    />
<Label
    x:Name="LblCombDataDesc2"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    IsVisible="False"
    FontSize="{x:Static Mobilize:Rsrc.TinyLabelFSize}"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalTextAlignment="End"
    />
```

Comment: Your description of the situation is confusing. You "specify fontsizes for each entity", but then you need to "go through and add fontsize". The first sounds like there is a fontsize; the second sounds like there is not a fontsize (yet). It would be MUCH clearer if you **show the actual code**. As it is now. And an example of the change you are considering making. Regardless, **it won't noticeably affect performance,** no matter how you do it.

Comment: I see your point -- I have edited.  The real nugget of info I was looking for was the "won't noticeably affect performance".  Thanks for that too.,

Answer (score -1):

Since you have many pages,you can use [Global Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) to achieve this.

1.Create a global style(e.g.`labelStyle`) in XAML

Here you can define properities for you View, for example:`FontSize`, `TextColor` and so on.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                    Value="Large"
                    />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" 
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" 
                    Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest"
                    Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                    Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

2.apply the labelStyle to the page's Label instances:

```
 <Label  Text="Welcome here" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
```

You can also Override styles as you want.

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application .